# Variable into Header Location

Tags: php, string

How can i include a variable and make it part the string.

```
header("Location: http://www." . "$_SESSION['domainname']");
```

The above code doesn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason why your code didn't work is due to how PHP handles indexed arrays inside strings.  You had:

```
"$_SESSION['domainname']"
```

But what PHP wanted to see was:

```
"$_SESSION[domainname]"
```

No single quotes this time.  You only omit those single quotes if you are referencing a variable directly inside a string.

Note that string interpolation, such as this, can work with simple arrays (`"$a[x]"`) but not with arrays of arrays (`"$a[x][y]"`) unless you use curly braces (`{$x}`, `{$a['x']['y']}`; note the single quotes in the curly braces--they aren't exactly like PHP's normal string interpolation, but rather more like referencing a variable elsewhere in PHP).

Comment: So it doesn't interpret it as a constant if i remove the single quotes from inside the brackets?

Comment: No, it won't interpret it as a constant as long as you are referencing the array index inside a string.  Outside a string, it would assume domainname is a constant.