# php dynamic url redirection using header location and sessions

Tags: php, session, redirect

I am trying to figure out the best way to do this and probably totally over thinking it.

I need users to submit their email before they can get the page contents.

they don't need to confirm at this point just submit any email. So I created a simple form with an email field and submit it to my process page using "POST"

However, I need them to be redirected to a dynamic url after submitting their email.

So I want to be able to put a variable in the url to the page I want to redirect to like this:

```
http://myurl.com/provide_email.php?url=newpage.html
```

On page provide_email.php I put :

```
<?php
session_start();

session_register('url');

$_SESSION['url'] = $_GET['url'];

?>
```

and echo the ouput on the same page (just to test it). So, on the same page it shows:

```
newpage.html
```

Then on my process.php page I put:

```
<?php

session_start();

$dynamicurl = $_GET['url'];

if(empty($_GET))
    echo "No GET variables";
else
    print_r($_GET); 


$host  = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$uri   = rtrim(dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']), '/\\');
$extra = 'folder1/folder2/';
header("Location: http://$host$uri/$extra/".$dynamicurl);


?>
```

However every time I submit the page it will not redirect to the url with the $dynamicurl variable.

I have also tried :

```
header("Location: http://$host$uri/$extra/$dynamicurl");
```

What am I doing the wrong?

The url has to be dynamic because I am creating the pages from a cms that ultimately the user will go to. I just want them to have to submit an email before they can get to each unique page.

Comment: `$dynamicurl = $_GET['url'];` why? you were trying to save the data into session variable, why are trying to get something from the query? `session_register` is DEPRECATED since php 5.3

Comment: Have you tested what `http://$host$uri/$extra/".$dynamicurl` actually results in?

Comment: $dynamicurl = $_GET['url'];
What si the use of this statement . I didn't find someting is passed in GET array , from query string

Answer (score 0):

Your debug statement is the problem:

```
if(empty($_GET))
    echo "No GET variables";
else
    print_r($_GET);
```

will start output, so the following `header()` cannot be honoured. I am sure your log is full of `warning: Cannot set header, output already started`

Use

```
if(empty($_GET))
    $message "No GET variables";
else
    $message=var_export($_GET,true);
```

and

```
echo $message;
```

AFTER the `header()` statement.

Comment: I put the debug statement just to see what was going wrong, but yes ...it is saying ... warning: Cannot set header, output already started
. But if dont have the if statment it WILL redirect but only to the directory: `http://myurl.com/folder1/folder2/` and never to the ending URL (newpage.html) 

If there is a better way to do this I am open. I just don't know any other way.

Comment: It shows me :  

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING in /home/webserver/public_html/test_site/process2.php on line 9

but line 9 is what I copied from your post line 9 and 11 are code highlighted as an error: `if(empty($_GET))
    $message "No GET variables";
else
    $message=var_export($_GET,true));`

Comment: I found my answer .. but new user can not answer their questions apparently. 

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/722836/variable-into-header-location][1]

This seems to have worked...
 I removed the debug altogether and chnaged the code to this :

    header("Location: http://$host$uri/$extra/"."$_SESSION[url]");

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/722836/variable-into-header-location

Comment: I edited my answer: There was a superfluous bracket in line 9.